# Multiple cameras pi zero w

Tags: camera

I'm new here. I would like to attach two cameras to a single raspberry pi zero w for depth mapping. Is it possibile to do that while keeping things small?

Comment: It's not possible. If you need two cameras there's a solution available using a CM3 and and a special adapter board. https://stereopi.com/#buy

Comment: @Dougie Shouldn't this do the work https://www.arducam.com/product/multi-camera-adapter-doubleplexer-stereo-module-v2-raspberry-pi-zero-3-b-4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this answer is a collection of links and two products but this is not a small topic and the suppliers have both provided hardware and their software tutorials are using open source software.

By default, the [Pi Zero boards](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero/?resellerType=home) have support for one camera built in via the CSI connector.

This gives you a few options:

1. Drop the Zero and base your design on the Compute Modules
2. Use a CSI camera and USB camera
3. Use a pair of USB cameras via a USB hub
4. Use a specialist HAT such as [Arducam](https://www.arducam.com) to give access to multiple cameras
5. Look at the [StereoPi boards](https://stereopi.com) (also on CrowdSupply)

Once you have addressed the hardware, software comes next:

1. The Robotic Operating System ([ROS](http://wiki.ros.org)) have done some work on this and a good breakdown of depth maps using this is to be found [on the Stereo Blog](https://stereopi.com/blog/ros-simple-depth-map-using-raspberry-pi)
2. Another option is to use OpenCV and that's documented on [the Arducam blog](https://www.arducam.com/raspberry-pi-stereo-camera-depth-mapping-arducam-tutorial/)